# Send Custom emails to culprits breaking the build in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am new to Azure devops tools (formerly known as vsts). I have the following use case:

I have a build pipeline which runs apex test classes via an ant build. I want to send an email containing the list of failing test classes to the corresponding culprits who broke the build.

I have already installed Send email plugin on my org. But it does not seem to have an option to send emails to the culprits breaking the build.

Any suggestions around the same?

Comment: How do you know who is breaking the build?  Are you using Git?  Have you considered adding [branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=vsts#build-validation) to the PR so it will be obvious they are not meeting the pass criteria after submitting the PR?

Answer (score 0):

if I know the person who broke the build by means of who requested it (for example by having a CI Build triggered upon changes) you can setup Notifications on Team Level.
On your team project go to the Project Settings --> Notifications and add a new Subscription. In there you can define that only the person that requested the build gets the notification:
[image: Notification Sample]

See more about notifications in general [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/howto-manage-team-notifications?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav)

If however you don't have the info directly in the build properties, you might need some custom script to fetch for example from the associated changes the authors and their respective emails. That would then be possible via the Azure DevOps Build REST API. However that approach would require some effort to be put in place.

Comment: but you cannot include 'list of failing test classes' in this subscription email.